Why won't Google maps allow dynamic lat and lon in angular?
I am trying to load some lat and longitudes for a map in angular, for some reason google maps won't allow.
I get the Data back from Firebase when I click a menu button every choice brings back a different array.
data looks like this
x_arr = [
    {
        "id" : "Plce ID",
        "name" : "Place",
        "location" : "Location",
        "lat": 00000000,
        "lon": 00000000
    }
]

Service looks like this
this.specific$ = this.x$.pipe(switchMap((x) => {
  return this.db.list('schedules', ref => ref.orderByChild('id').equalTo(x)).valueChanges();   
}));

this.specific$.subscribe({next:(value) => {
    this.x_arr = value;
});

The component with the Map
 constructor(public f: FireService){}
 center: google.maps.LatLngLiteral = {lat: this.f.x_arr[0]?.lat, lng: this.f.x_arr[0]?.lon };

Component HTML
   <google-map height="1080"
        width="1920"
        [center]="center"/>

On first click this is the error
InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral with finite coordinates: in property lat: not a number
If I click around a few times. The Value is then pushed to the map and then the map works.
BUT ! When I choose a different value the should update with a new lat and lon the first one persists and the map never changes.
What's wrong here ?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng

That does not help !

Google Maps allows dynamic changes for center coordinates. So it is some issue in your code.
In your component constructor, ensure that the initial coordinates are set correctly and are not null. Here in your code:
center: google.maps.LatLngLiteral = { lat: this.f.x_arr[0]?.lat, lng: this.f.x_arr[0]?.lon };

"000000" is not a correct number, if you have this in the initialization. Null also is not a correct number. Try to set the correct initial existing lat/lng. Or you may inialize the map only when first coordinates are received from service.
Then, when your service changes the lat/lng value, try to explicitly subscribe to these changes from your components. Print the changed values in the console to ensure that the new center coordinates are set correctly.
Finally, you may use ChangeDetectorRef to let Angular explicitly know that changes have occurred and re-rendering is required. You need to add it in the constructor:
constructor (private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef). 

And then, after each change of center coordinates, you may call:
this.cdRef.detectChanges();

